# Scrolltop function add class after a determined number of pixels scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

My friend bought a theme for his store at Theme Forest, and as I know a little about CSS and HTML he asked me for custom improvements on the theme. One of the things he asked me is that the "Sticky Add to Cart header" that displays fixed on the top of the page after a determined number of pixels are scrolled past, that is later than its displaying right now. I did some research about how to implement that in the actual JS and Jquery code of the store, but I had no success since I know nothing about JS/JQuery. Here's the code:

```
_initStickyInfo: function() {
        if ($(this.selectors.stickCart).length) {
            var e = this,
                t = 0,
                a = $("header").outerHeight() + $(".mini-breadcrumb").outerHeight() + $(".product-section-wrapper").offset().top;
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                var e = $(this).scrollTop();
                e > a ? $("body").addClass("show-sticky-info-product") : $("body").removeClass("show-sticky-info-product"), t = e
            }), $("body").on("click", ".sticky-button.button-cart", function() {
                0 < $(e.selectors.addToCart).length && $(e.selectors.addToCart).trigger("click")
            })
        }
    },
```

How do I make that code add the "show-sticky-info-product" class only after the user scrolls the page a little more, not right after the user starts scrolling?

Here's the link to the page with the HTML and CSS if you need it: [link](https://desconton.myshopify.com/products/unisex-solid-backpack-school-travel-bag-double-shoulder-bag-zipper-bag)

Thanks in advance

Comment: hey bro check my below answer i might help you well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do `$(this).scrollTop() + 40px;` where 40px would be however many pixels you want it to scroll past.

Or try `.scrollTop(a);` where a is what you want height to be.

Answer (score 1):

you can handle class while scroll by the following code.

refer the below example:-

```js
window.onscroll = function (e) {
    console.log(window.scrollY); // Value of scroll Y in px
    if(scrollY >200){
    $('div').addClass('green');
    }
    if(scrollY <200){
    $('div').removeClass('green');
    }
};
```

```css
.green{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div >hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div >hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div><div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div >hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div><div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div >hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
```